# Django: permission denied when trying to access database after restore (migration)

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a django 1.4 app with a populated postgres 9.1 database in development server locally. After successful deployment, I wanted to move the data from local to online database, so I used:

```
pg_dump -f dump.sql -Ox database
```

and then restored on the server with:

```
psql -1 -f dump.sql database
```

Now trying to login online to the website admin throws a "permission denied for relation django_session" exception. I've tried to dump the data with/without -Ox switch and all its combinations but without success. I am also dropping the database and recreating it from scratch on the server with the correct owner as set in settings.py.

If I run a normal syndb without a restore then everything works well.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It turns out that you should grant explicit ownership of all objects in the database to the owner after restore. The owner is not a superuser. It's not enough to only set the owner at database creation time. The final solution for migration goes like this:

on the client:

```
pg_dump -f dump.sql -Ox database
```

on the server:

```
su postgres    
dropdb database
createdb database -O user
psql database -f dump.sql
```

and then to set the privileges:

```
psql database -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to user;"
psql database -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to user;"
psql database -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to user;"
```

Note that we could've run the sql command in psql console but this form is easily embeddable in scripts and such.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this from `postgres` user:

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump -f dump.sql -Ox database
```

Or just pass `-U` flag:

```
pg_dump -f dump.sql -Ox database -U postgres
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, my client os is windows 7 and there is no postgres su. I just open a DOS prompt and dump.

Comment: Nothing changed, still having the same problem. FWIW, I am using a special user on the server (which does not exist on the client) and this is reflected in setting.py, when I recreate the database on the server (prior to the restore), I use something like: createdb database -O special_user and then I restore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed mine. I saved myself a ton of a headache by simply changing the user to match the current logged in user of the destination server where the import will happen.

In my case, the imported db had a user of x (x was also the username for the machine it was running on), and the destination machine had a username of y, and a postgres user of y too.

Therefore, I simply changed the Database User and Password in my Django settings to match the destination machine's y user details.

Then did this:

`$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES DATABASE ON mydb TO y;`

Sipping some kool-aid now!