# Transfering postgreSQL DB from one server to another

Tags: bash, postgresql, ssh

I am using this command to attempt to transfer a DB

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U OLD_SERVER_USER_NAME site_db | psql -h NEW_SERVER_IP -U postgres site_db
```

It asks me for a password, which I give and then nothing happens, it just hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, to avoid the password prompt, you can set the environment variable `PGPASSWORD`.

In terms of it hanging, it's quite possible that the piping is "eating" an error that you would otherwise see.

Try breaking it up into separate commands, something like:

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U OLD_SERVER_USER_NAME site_db > db.dmp.sql && psql -h NEW_SERVER_IP -U postgres -f db.dmp.sql site_db
```

And see if you get any errors from either command.

Comment: I ended up manually transferring the DB using the answer in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233046/django-permission-denied-when-trying-to-access-database-after-restore-migratio . Thanks for your help though.