# Unable to restore postgres database of Django app because of database ownership discrepancies

Tags: python, django, postgresql, azure, heroku

I am trying to restore a postgres data dump for a Django app of mine. The data dump was extracted from Heroku, and `pg_restore latest.dump -d mydb -U postgres` was run on an Azure VM with Linux on it.

The user on Heroku is called `uauv8b9v4`. There's no similar user on Azure. So when I ran pg_restore on Azure, I got tons of `role does not exist` errors. E.g.:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 241; 1259 44416 TABLE links_grouptraffic uauv8b9v4
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  role "uauv8b9v4" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE public.links_grouptraffic OWNER TO uauv8b9v4;
```

Now accessing my Django app at example.cloudapp.net just shows the following error:

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError Exception Value:

permission denied for relation links_link

Exception Location: /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in execute, line 54
```

Note that I got exactly the same **permission denied** error if I run pg_restore with `-Ox`; it doesn't help.

Next, I dropped the database, and ran `CREATE USER uauv8b9v4 with password 'password';`, `CREATE DATABASE mydb;` and `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb to uauv8b9v4;`. I thought now if I ran `pg_restore latest.dump -d MYDB -U uauv8b9v4`, my problem will be solved.

Instead I got 3 errors:

1) **Must be owner of extension plpgsql**:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2584; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
```

2) **Permission denied to create extension "pg_stat_statements"**:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 249; 3079 16622 EXTENSION pg_stat_statements 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "pg_stat_statements"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
    Command was: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements WITH SCHEMA public;
```

3) **Extension "pg_stat_statements" does not exist**:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2585; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION pg_stat_statements 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  extension "pg_stat_statements" does not exist
    Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION pg_stat_statements IS 'track execution statistics of all SQL statements executed';
```

Trying to access my website still gives me the original `permission denied` error.

What do I do to fix this situation? Secondly, I've also begun wondering whether I need to run `syncdb` in this process at some stage? I tried going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233046/django-permission-denied-when-trying-to-access-database-after-restore-migratio), but it hasn't solved my problem. I feel I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try restoring like this: `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump` where `myuser` is the superuser on your linux machine (you don't have to have a user named `uauv8b9v4` to make this work) And no need to run `syncdb` if this is done right.